# Сколько памяти занимают ссылки?

Tags: c++

Сколько памяти занимают ссылки?

Comment: в c++. Допустим есть : int a = 0; int &b = a; сколько памяти требуется для хранения b?

Comment: sizeof и посмотреть - не?

В, практически, любом случае занимают меньше исходного значения если вы об этом ( если речь именно о ссылке ) т.к. хранит в себе адрес памяти а не его содержимое

Comment: Да..... ну у Вас и вопрос. Вы думаете что мы тут екстрасенсы?

Comment: sizeof выдает 4. Ведь в сути создается еще один идентификатор для переменной а, который будет работать с той же памятью и тем же размером данных, что и а. Это объясняет значение sizeof. А сам идентификатор на сколько затратно хранить ,интересно.

Comment: sizeof выдает 4 - какие еще могут быть вопросы?О_о

Answer (score 10):

Если ссылка является просто алиасом переменой, то скорее всего ничего не занимает (будет оптимизирована компилятором), а если ссылка — аргумент функции, то занимает столько же, сколько и указатель.

`sizeof` в данном случае использовать нельзя, так как в c++ ссылки «прозрачны». Оператор `sizeof` в случае применения к ссылке «думает», что нужно вывести размер объекта на который она ссылается.

Answer (score 9):

Ссылки в языке С++ являются реализацией концепции *альтернативного имени* для существующего объекта. Т.е. на уровне концепций языка, ссылки не занимают никакой памяти вообще. Ссылки в языке С++ не являются *объектами* и по этой причине формально не имеют места в хранилище (storage).

Другими словами, на уровне языка вот в таком вот примере

```
int x = 5;
int &r = x;
```

нет никакой разницы между "основным" именем объявленной переменной `x` и ее альтернативным именем `r`. Основное имя переменной никакой памяти для себя не требует, соответственно и альтернативное имя тоже никакой памяти не требует.

Все вышесказанное справедливо на уровне языка, но, как правило, практическая реализация языковых концепций обычно требует дополнительных накладных расходов. Понятно, что полная аналогия между ссылкой и именем объекта возможна только в том случае, когда значение ссылки предсказуемо на стадии компиляции. В такой ситуации каждый уважающий себя компилятор просто "отоптимизирует" такую ссылку нафиг и никакой памяти она занимать не будет.

Во всех остальных случаях ссылки реализуются компилятором, как "замаскированные" указатели, т.е. непереназначаемые указатели, к которым не надо применять оператор `*` для разыменования. Соответственно и памяти такая ссылка занимают ровно столько, сколько указатель.

Вот и все.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуем такой тестовый код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct aa {
    int a1;
    long a2; 
};

int main() {
    int a =1;
    long b = 1L;
    struct aa ast = {1, 1L};
    int & ar = a;
    long & br = b;
    struct aa & aar = ast;
    cout << sizeof (ar) << "   " << sizeof (br) << "  " << sizeof (aar) << endl;
    return 0;
}

g++ test.cpp -o a

./a

4   8  16
```

Ubuntu 11.04 x86_64, g++-4.5

Вывод - ссылка имеет тот же размер, что и объект (в широком смысле), на который она ссылается.

На самом деле, ссылка в памяти не занимает нисколько места, потому что это просто иное имя для переменной. Другое дело при передачи параметра по ссылке в функцию. Там скорее всего реально передается указатель, но нужно посмотреть генерируемый ассемблеровский код.

P.S. Это очень распространенная ошибка - путать ссылку с указателем.

Comment: >На самом деле, ссылка в памяти не занимает нисколько места, потому что это просто иное имя для переменной. 

 Это уже оптимизация компилятора. А без неё ссылка занимает 4 или 8 байт.

Comment: В инструкциях процессора все обращения к переменным, находящимся в памяти, идут через адрес этой переменной. При объявлении переменной в С++ ее имя привязывается к определенному адресу. Ссылка - это другое имя для этого адреса, поэтому на уровне ассемблера скорее всего не различить, где было обращение через оригинальное имя или через ссылку. 

Указатель - это переменная, т.е. выделенная область память, содержащая адрес другой области памяти. Разницу чувствуете?

Comment: @GLmonster: Нет, это не оптимизация компилятора. Это именно то, как идея ссылки формально определяется на уровне языка. Тут скорее наоборот: когда компилятор вынужден реализовывать ссылку через указатель (параметры функций, поля классов и т.п.), это является "прозой жизни", мешающей компилятору реализовывать "светлые и чистые" идеи языка С++.

Answer (score 3):

В зависимости от разрядности платформы. Если компилировать под `x86`, то 4 байта, если `x64` - то 8.

Answer (score 2):

Ссылка как правило реализуется как обертка над указателем, насколько я помню в стандарте нет требований к реализации ссылок. Там описано только как ссылка должна себя вести.

Но если уж вам необходимо знать размер самой ссылки, то `sizeof(T &)` вам не поможет, вы получете размер `T`. Однако можно сделать нехитрый финт ушами - завернуть ссылку в структуру:

```
struct foo
{
    char bytes[128];
};

struct bar
{
    foo & bytes_ref;
};

auto f = sizeof(foo);
auto b = sizeof(bar);
```

Так вот, у меня под VC2012 предсказуемо `f = 128` и для x86 и для x64. Под x86 `b = 4`, под x64 `b = 8`, что тоже предсказуемо.

Comment: Конечно предсказуемо, потому что именно столько занимает в памяти пустая структура (4 или 8 в зависимости от архитектуры). Она же тоже имеет указатель. Создайте второе поле ссылку и увидите, что размер структуры не измениться. Вывод: ссылка не занимает место в памяти, это просто псевдоним другой переменной, которая в памяти уже есть.

Answer (score 1):

Провел эксперимент (у меня система х32)

```
//-----------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a;
    int *pa = &a;
    short int b;
    short int *pb = &b;
    long double c;
    long double *pc = &c;
    char d;
    char *pd = &d;
    cout << "a = " << sizeof(a) << endl;
    cout << "&a = " << sizeof(&a) <<endl;
    cout << "pa = " << sizeof(pa) << endl;
    cout << "*pa = " << sizeof(*pa) <<endl;
    cout << "b = " << sizeof(b) << endl;
    cout << "&b = " << sizeof(&b) <<endl;
    cout << "pb = " << sizeof(pb) << endl;
    cout << "*pb = " << sizeof(*pb) <<endl;
    cout << "c = " << sizeof(c) << endl;
    cout << "&c = " << sizeof(&c) <<endl;
    cout << "pc = " << sizeof(pc) << endl;
    cout << "*pc = " << sizeof(*pc) <<endl;
    cout << "d = " << sizeof(d) << endl;
    cout << "&d = " << sizeof(&d) <<endl;
    cout << "pd = " << sizeof(pd) << endl;
    cout << "*pd = " << sizeof(*pd) <<endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
//-------------------------------------------
```

в итоге размеры

```
&a = pa = &b = pb = &c = pc = &d = pd = 4 байта
a = *pa = 4 байта
b = *pb = 2 байта
c = *pc = 10 байт
d = *pd = 1 байт
```

Вывод адресс занимает 4 байта

Насчет того занимает ли место ссылка в программе не знаю как проверить

Comment: чет не влазит сообщение полностью :(

Comment: вобщем &a = pa = &b = pb = &c = pc = &d = pd = 4 байта

Comment: И какое отношение этот эксперимент имеет к рассматриваемому вопросу?

Answer (score 0):

Если ты хотел бы узнать сколько занимает указатель на некоторый тип, то это,
как сказал GLmonster, зависит от разрядности платформы. 
То есть если мы создаём

```
int a=5;
int *b=&a;
```

то b указывает на a и занимает 4 байта.

При выделении памяти

```
int a=5;
int &b=a;
```

происходит почти то же самое. Мы в неявном виде выделяем указатель b (4 байта)
и говорим что он указывает на a.

Вот этой командой мы задаём статически память для a.

```
int a;
```

То есть после компиляции в exe будет находится информация о том как будут распологаться ячейки памяти в RAM и как к ним обратиться. После запуска приложения произойдёт определение их в оперативной памяти. Для типа указателей та же картина. Но на что он будет указывать мы можем изменить в ходе программы.
Например так:

```
int a=5;
int &b=a;
int w=5;
&b=&w;
```

В данном случае так как b указатель мы попросим чтобы он указывал на память w и нам разрешат это сделать.

Надеюсь в тему и всё понятно. =)

Comment: А почему не попробовали с другими типами переменных: long, float, double, структурку какую-нибудь, класс?

Comment: Уважаемый mikillskegg!
Может я конечно ошибаюся =)
Но. В последнем примере который я привёл Мы переобозначаем так называемую ссылку &b на другую область памяти на w. (BC++ 3.1) Следовательно в переводе на ассмеблер это переобозначение должно остаться! А вдруг мы напишем с неким условием?
if (tt=1) &b=&w;
else &b=&a;
Как это будет ассемблер обрабатывать-то? А tt мы считываем из файла, например. Думаю он так и оставит условие и где-то всё же будет храниться указатель b (на w или на что-то иное).

Comment: Собственно из этого наблюдения я и сделал вывод, что "ссылка" всё равно будет указателем. И память по неё выделится именно 4 (ну или 8 =)) байт. 
А когда мы говрим sizeof(b) то само собой мы обращаемся к тому что лежит по адресу, ну и соответсвенно возвращаем размер этого чего-то long или struct...

Comment: Ну да ладно. Тут надо лезть в генерируемый ассемблерный код, а мне сейчас как-то лень. Возможно, что разные компиляторы себя по-разному ведут.

Comment: Возможно и по-разному... =)

Comment: "`&b=&w` и нам резрешат это сделать" - это где вы такое видели? Это даже компилироваться не будет. Язык С++ не предоставляет никаких возможностей переставления ссылки на другой объект и никак, кроме как низкруровневыми хаками, такую операцию выполнить не удастся. Ни о каком `&b=&w` речи, разумеется, быть не может.

Answer (score -1):

Ссылка - это просто скрытый указатель.
В 32-битных программах это 4 байта, а в 64-битных - 8.

Размер указателя можно вывести при помощи sizeof:

```
sizeof (void*)
```

Comment: "When applied to a reference or a reference type, the result is the size of the referenced type". Ваш `sizeof(int&)` возвращает размер типа `int`, а не размер ссылки.

Comment: @Abyx, да, про sizeof я был неправ. Но ссылка - это скрытый указатель.